# How can I save prevState three times in reverse?

Tags: reactjs

Because `CSStransitions` makes components render three times, I need to store the `prevState` three times backwards.

Any ideas about how to do it? Should I use `useEffect` and `useRef`?

Here is an example so it will be more clear:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    
const 3statesBackwards = 0;
// so when count gets to 3, 3statesBackwards is 0,
// if count get to 8, 3statesBackwards will be 5.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not new useState property that holds those values?

```
const [prevCount, setPrevCount] = useState({lastCurrent: 0,prev1: 0, prev2: 0, prev3: 0});

useEffect( () => {

  setPrevCount( prev => ({
    lastCurrent: count,
    prev1: prev.lastCurrent,
    prev2: prev.prev1,
    prev3: prev.prev2
  })

}, [count]);
```